# Do you have to implement multiple iterators in a STL-like class?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm quite familiar with the STL and how to use it.  My question is...

If I were to implement my own STL container type, how are the internal iterators defined? STL classes tend to have sequential or random-access iterators, const_ versions of these, and stream iterators.

Are these iterators all fully-defined in every STL class, or is there some sort of base class that you inherit from to gain most of the iterator functionality?  Does anyone know a good reference for how to implement a class that supports these different kinds of iterators?

Comment: it depends on the container, for example only some containers have random access iterators. About the `const`, I think every iterator has a `const` version

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that part - only sequence containers have random access, associative can't because it would invalidate the implicit ordering.  Do you know if the const version is the same iterator just typedefed though? Because I thought it had different functions exposed to it somehow.

Comment: @wiso (Out|In)putIterators usually don't. e.g. There is no way to have a `const_back_inserter`.

Comment: @w00te: the const_iterator has the same functions except for adding `const` to the return types in the appropriate places. `container::const_iterator` isn't the same as `const container::iterator`, so it's not just a typedef, but if you're writing your data structure from scratch you can generally write a template that will do for `container::iterator` with `T` as the template parameter, and `container::const_iterator` with `const T`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you only have to implement `iterator` and `const_iterator`.
If reverse iterators are desired, they can be obtained using
instantiations of `std::reverse_iterator`.  The stream iterators will use
`operator>>` and `operator<<`; typically, they aren't appropriate for a
container (and none of the standard containers provides them).

Comment: I think you can go a bit further and say that `std::reverse_iterator` *must* be used for reversible containers. See Table 66 (23.1/9), it says exactly what the types `X::reverse_iterator` and `X::const_reverse_iterator` are. The typedef in the container could go around the houses a bit to get there, if it wants, but the way I read it a different type that behaves like `reverse_iterator<X::iterator>` is not permitted, since a conforming program could tell the difference (e.g. by comparing the typeids).

Comment: @Steve Jessop Maybe.  To tell the truth, the idea of implementing the reverse iterator in any other way never really occurred to me.

Comment: Me either. I guess if for some peculiar reason it was easier to write the code to iterate over the container in reverse order, you might prefer to write that iterator and use it as `X::reverse_iterator`, then have `reverse_iterator<X::reverse_iterator>` as `X::iterator`. But I only invented that just now, I've never thought about doing it, and I can't immediately think of a data structure that would have a bidirectional iterator, and that you'd care which order you go.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need two different iterators to be fully stdlib compliant.

You can get most typedefs right with inheriting from `std::iterator` but this wont give you any help with the actual implementation.

[Boost.Iterator Facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html#iterator-facade-and-adaptor) tries to simplify defining your own iterators and the tutorial is quite helpful.

Should you attempt to do it without helpers you should think about what concept your iterator models and then look at the tables in §24 of the C++ standard. They describe all operations you need to support and what the intended semantics are.

Comment: A quick recap of the iterator concepts and of the content of the `<iterator>` header (that contains `std::iterator` and `std::iterator_traits`) can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/) (<insert here the usual remarks about the unreliability of cplusplus.com>)

Comment: One note: usually, if you don't start from scratch, you already have an iterator, somewhat. In this case, the Iterator Adaptor is easier :)

Comment: Am I the only one who finds this answer misleading? It makes it sound as if you have to implement iterators for each category that you support, which is false.

Comment: @Konrad I don't know how one would get that impression. Feel free to address the issue with an edit.

Comment: @pmr: I didn't get the impression of one per concept, but I don't expect "many" to mean 2, and hence I was sort of wondering what others you had in mind. I guess Konrad was still wondering that when he got to the bit about iterator concepts.

Comment: @pmr The first sentence is unconstrained: “you need many iterators to be fully … compliant”; note that the OP is operating under the assumption that STL containers all implement multiple iterator categories, and you basically say “yes, and you need to do the same”.